# PySpark pivoting, output in column form

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe of stock trades within a single 24-hr period. Columns include: DATE, TIME NAME, VOL, COST. (Again, date is somewhat superfluous since all transactions took place on the same day.

I want the following columns: NAME, DATE, HOUR, VOL, where each row represents a stock ticker, such as AAPL, and VOL represents the number of trades of that stock within that HOUR.

In excel, I think this would be most easily solved using a pivot table. What is the PySpark equivalent?

Here is a sample from my dataframe to illustrate my data:

```py
+--------+--------+--------+----+------+
|    DATE|  TIME  |  NAME  |VOL | COST |
+--------+--------+--------+----+------+
|20120103|09:04:08|    AAPL| 500|409.21|
|20120103|09:06:49|    AAPL| 100|409.41|
|20120103|09:21:10|    AAPL| 100|409.49|
|20120103|09:26:28|    AAPL| 100|409.04|
|20120103|09:29:55|    AAPL| 100| 410.3|
|20120103|09:30:00|    AAPL| 200|409.91|
|20120103|09:30:04|    AAPL| 100|410.11|
+--------+--------+--------+----+------+
```

The following steps have gotten me decently close, but not with the columns desired.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def fix_time(time):
  return time[:2]

udf_myFunction = udf(fix_time)
df1 = df.withColumn("TIME_H", udf_myFunction("TIME")) 

import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df1.groupBy("NAME").pivot("TIME_H").agg(psf.max("VOL")).show()

>>>>

+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  NAME  | 09| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15|
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|    AAPL|800|437|800|400|808|800|700|
|    GOOG|300|400|527|200|450|300|700|
|     IBM|910|992|800|500|300|500|900|
|    MSFT|900|900|900|900|794|800|800|
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Again, I'd really like this same information, however, with the columns:  NAME, DATE, HOUR, VOL.

Is it fairly straight forward taking what I've got and converting it to what I want or is there a more effective method to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to aggregate all tickers at the hourly to get the total number of trades booked. If that's case then below can help and it's output for your sample AAPL ticker.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy('NAME','DATE', df.TIME.substr(1,2).alias('HOUR')).agg(f.sum('VOL').alias('VOL')).show()
+----+--------+----+----+
|NAME|    DATE|HOUR| VOL|
+----+--------+----+----+
|AAPL|20120103|  09|1200|
+----+--------+----+----+
```

Happy to change solution if your requirement is different.